# Lots of confusing git conflicts

Tags: android, git, macos, bitbucket

I have very confusing issue with conflicts during pull request at bitbucket. I have 137 conflicts like those below. How to fix it and prevent this from happening in the future? It's Android Studio's project on macOs.

[image: First conflict]

[image: Second conflict]

[image: Third conflict]

As you can see I've just added some lines, but git treats it as conflicts.

Below you can find conflicts with merge.conflictStyle=diff3.
[image: 1 conf]

[image: 2 conf]

[image: 3 conf]

I still have no idea why it's conflict instead of edition.

Comment: We would need to know what those sections of code looked like on the common ancestor to be able to know what is going on. Can you try merging again with `merge.conflictStyle=diff3`?

Comment: @eftshift0 could you take a look on it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your diff3 screenshots provide the answer.  (Aside: don't use screenshots here.  Cut-and-paste the *text* directly.  In this case that should drop the gutter information with the line numbers, but that's OK.  See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).)

Remember that in Git, a *merge* is about *combining work*.  There are *three* commits involved:

- You, on your branch, started with some commit.  Git calls this the *merge base* commit.
- They, on their branch, started with *this very same commit*.

So Git first runs *two* `git diff` commands (or the internal equivalent anyway).  One compares this merge base to *your* version of the code, and the second `git diff` compares this merge base to *their* version of the code.

I'll start with the middle conflict.

The diff3 style diff includes the merge base code (from commit `ce442625`), where we can read—I have retyped this, so I may have added some typos<sup>1</sup>—that the original line said:

```
    chage_lang.setOnClickListener { openDialogToSelectLang() }
```

This is clearly defective: it should read `change_lang` rather than `chage_lang`.

In *your* commit, in HEAD, you *kept this line* but *added one more blank line after it*.  This is one "diff hunk".

In *their* commit, in `feature/dark_mode`, *they* fixed the spelling and *replaced* the single blank line with a non-blank line, to get:

```
    change_lang.setOnClickListener { openDialogToSelectLang() }
    change_theme.setOnClickListener { openDialogToSelectTheme() }
```

Here, Git does not know whether to keep your added blank line, or keep their removal-and-replacement of a blank line; it does not know whether to keep the wrong spelling, `chage_lang`, or use the corrected spelling, `change_lang`.  So it produces a conflict: you must select the correct resolution.

Just below this, the last conflict is similar: the *merge base* version says:

```
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard_margin"
    android:background="@color/white"
```

In *your* version, you *changed the first line" to read "8dp" and *kept the second line intact*, but in *their* version they *kept the first line intact and deleted the second line*.  Once again, Git does not know whether to take your version, their version, some combination of both, or what.  *You* must choose the correct resolution here.

The *first* diff is the most confusing: here, the set of lines taken from the merge base version is *empty*.  The change on your side is that *you* added one *blank line*, while *they* added one *non-blank line reading:*

```
    setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, ...
```

As in both other cases, Git does not know whether it should add your blank line, or their line, or both, or neither, or what.  *You* must choose.

Edit the file in question to have the *correct combination* (and to no longer contain the conflict markers), or use a merge tool to achieve the same effect.  Then use `git add` on the resulting file, or use a merge tool—probably the same merge tool, all as one thing—to run `git add` *for you*.  The `git add` updates the copies of the files in Git's *staging area* so that Git knows the correct resolution.

(Git assumes that whatever you told it is correct, *is* correct, so be sure you tell it the right thing here!  In other words, make sure the *entire file* is correct.  Usually that means you should *test* your merge resolution before giving it to Git.  That's one reason I don't like `git mergetool`: you do the merge, and then `git mergetool` immediately tells Git it's right, and if it's not right, you have to start over.<sup>2</sup>)

---

<sup>1</sup>This risk-of-typos is *why* the "ask" page suggests using cut-and-paste.

<sup>2</sup>You can start over with just this one file, and/or edit-and-debug it without re-creating the conflict, but it's now harder to see the original three input files.  Using `git checkout -m` to re-create the conflict works, but that loses your resolution.  Once you know *exactly* what you and Git are doing, there are workarounds for all of this, but overall this whole user-experience seems like a bad one, to me.

Comment: Great feedback, @torek (for a change :-D). I would only add: the first 2 conflicts are **non-conflicts** from our point of view. git would have gotten it right when merging **if** on **our** branch we hadn't included totally unnecessary empty lines.